# Autolayout (VFL) for View that is added with code not storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, visual-format-language

If I add views from storyboard I can handle their autolayout contraints via code, but if I try this on a view that is added via code, can't handle it.

I'm calling the code below in my viewDidLoad() but doesn't works, what is the missing part?

```
    var testView = UIView()
    testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    self.view.addSubview(testView)

    let views : [String : AnyObject] = ["testView": testView]
    var allConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|-[testView(100)]",
        options: [],
        metrics: nil,
        views: views)
    allConstraints += verticalConstraint

    let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-[testView(200)]",
        options: [],
        metrics: nil,
        views: views)
    allConstraints += horizontalConstraint

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(allConstraints)
```

ps: also tried these lines but didn't help

```
    self.view.addConstraints(verticalConstraint)
    self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraint)
```

Comment: what's the error or layout constraint warning that you get?

Comment: @ozgur tons of error I get even can't copy/paste here but mainly "Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint" and if you have time you can just copy/paste into a new project's main view controller's viewdidload to see all problems I get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn off translation of autoresizing masks to constraints. By default its set to `true` and if you tend to forget this, it will add constraints which you did not intend to.

You can set this to false by

```
var myView = UIView()
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(myView)
```

> [translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
>
> If this property’s value is YES, the system creates a set of
>   constraints that duplicate the behavior specified by the view’s
>   autoresizing mask. By default, the property is set to YES for any view
>   you programmatically create. If you add views in Interface Builder,
>   the system automatically sets this property to NO.

Comment: thank you, you saved my day! I tried to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints of my view's superview before, not the view itself :/